# Chrome extensions that runs JS before every page loads using content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to write a chrome extension that needs to inject JS before any page loads. I am having trouble getting my JS to execute.

This is what I have for my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "testOne",
  "description": "This extension inject js",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is what I have in my JS right now:

```
alert('test');
console.log('you tried to log');
```

Why am I not seeing any alerts of console events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I restarted chrome and my JS worked.

It seems that chrome can't add new content scripts on the fly. Once you add one to your manifest and restart chrome, you can edit the JS file & reload the extension to run your new code.

Comment: In 2024 just reload the extension, no need to restart Chrome.